# How "beforeunload" and "unload" events work?

Tags: javascript

As I understood correctly when user closes a tab or clicks on the link or, even, updates a page "beforeunload" and then "unload" events are triggered. First, I can't register an event handler (some code snippets doesn't work):

1. From [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) example I have written the following:

   ```
   window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue("Are you sure?");
   });
   ```

   and it doesn't work (I expected dialog appearance)
2. Also I have tried this:

   ```
   window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
        return "Are you sure?";
   });
   ```

   and it doesn't work as well
3. From [w3school docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp) I have written:

   ```
   window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        return "Are you sure?";
   }
   ```

   and it work! But why the previous doesn't work?

**How about triggering on browser or tab closing?** Is it possible "to do some operations" when the user closes tab or browser? To be more clear, I want to delete some cookies which refers to his current session when the user closes tab or browser. Or I need to do something like this?

```
window._link_was_clicked = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
  if (window._link_was_clicked) {
    return; // abort beforeunload
  }
  // your event handling
};

jQuery(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {
  window._link_was_clicked = true;
});
```

Here is full demo code which I have written:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            angular
                .module("app", [])
                .controller("Controller", function ($scope) {
                    $scope.username = localStorage.getItem("username") || "";
                    $scope.setCookie = function () {
                        console.log("Set Cookie");
                        localStorage.setItem("username", "Denys");
                        $scope.username = localStorage.getItem("username");
                    }
                    $scope.deleteCookie = function () {
                        console.log("Delete Cookie");
                        localStorage.removeItem("username");
                        $scope.username = localStorage.getItem("username") || "";
                    }
                })
                .run(function () {
                    console.log("run()");
                    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.returnValue("Are you sure?");
                        return "Are you sure?";
                    });
                    window.addEventListener("unload", function (event) {
                        localStorage.removeItem("username");
                    });
                    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                        return "Are you sure?";
                    }
                });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="Controller">
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <p ng-if="username">{{username}}</p>
        <p>
            <button ng-click="setCookie()">Set Cookie</button>
            <button ng-click="deleteCookie()">Delete Cookie</button>
        </p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you realize that more than closing the tabs triggers those events?

Answer (score 0):

You have added parentheses in the first one even though there aren't any in the MDN documentation:
[image]

The event should also fire if the tab is closed.
If you set the cookie expiration correctly you can make it so they delete automatically.